# How to modify pointer to array of structs inside another struct by reference

Tags: c

I am trying to modify a struct that is a pointer inside of another struct within a function and then have the change reflect back outside of the function.

I have simplified my code below to the exact issue I am having.  I understand that inside my function, as currently constructed, I am modifying the value of x, rather than the utilizing the address of x to modify, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to properly modify each `particle` in the array. I have tried

```
b[0].p->x++;
```

inside the for loop in the `test` function, but that only changes `p[0]` from 1 to 5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
        int x;
} particle_t;

typedef struct {
        int num_part;
        particle_t* p;
} bins;

void test (bins *b) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                b[0].p[i].x++;
        }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        particle_t *particles = (particle_t*) malloc (4 * sizeof(particle_t));
        particles[0].x = 1;
        particles[1].x = 2;
        particles[2].x = 3;
        particles[3].x = 4;

        bins *b = (bins*) malloc (4 * sizeof(bins));
        b[0].num_part = 1;
        b[0].p = (particle_t*) malloc (4 * sizeof(particle_t));

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                b[0].p[i] = particles[i];
        }

        test(b);

        printf("%d %d %d %d\n",particles[0].x,particles[1].x,particles[2].x,particles[3].x);

        return 0;
}
```

After running the `test` function, I expected that printing out `particles[i].x` would yield 2, 3, 4, and 5, but I am still receiving 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: "After running the `test` function, I expected that" - the program terminates after running the `test` function...

Comment: I forgot the `printf` line, sorry! updated!

Comment: You are printing the particles array, not the b[0].p array

Comment: yes, I updated again, I am want the changes done on the b[0].p array to be reflected in the particles array

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int main (int argc, char **argv)`  To avoid the compiler outputting two warning messages about unused parameters,  When the parameters to `main()` are not used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `bins *b = (bins*) malloc (4 * sizeof(bins));`  and `particle_t *particles = (particle_t*) malloc (4 * sizeof(particle_t));`  1) In c, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "malloc failed" );`   3) before exiting the program, always pass allocated memory pointers to `free()` to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: thanks @user3629249! I am `free()`ing in my code, just forgot to add to the snippet :)

Comment: we have to work with what you actually post, we cannot read your mind, not read code that is not posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are allocating a new array for b[0].p and copying the particles array to b[0].p array. Your function changes the memory in b[0].p and not the memory pointed by particles.

Instead of malloc just make your b[0].p array point to particles.

Summing up, change

```
b[0].p = (particle_t*) malloc (4 * sizeof(particle_t));
```

to

```
b[0].p = particles;
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind helping me take this one step further? How would I make this work if I wanted to split the 4 particles I have in this example among 2 bins, as an example?

Comment: You could, for instance, make the first bin point to the beginning of particles{ b[0].p = particles; } and the second point to the other half { b[1].p = particles + 2; }. But I don't see why you are doing this kind of stuff. Seems to me that there is no need for the particles array. Just allocate each bin with its own particles...

Comment: If you insist in having everyone sharing the same memory at least make sure that each bin only access its share of the particles array (Make sure the for iterate only for each bin size (num_part)).

Comment: Thanks again! The reason I have the 2 different arrays is because in the grander scheme of my program, the particles are set with position, velocity, and acceleration and then interact with each other, but only if they are close enough to each other within a predefined space. The bins collect the particles so that I can limit the number of particles each particle checks to see if an interaction should occur.

And yes, I am iterating over num_parts, I had simplified the code here to highlight where I was getting stuck.